# Remote Desktop Gateway MMC not showing some connections under "Monitoring"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

This is a short question: I have a Remote Desktop Gateway server on Windows Server 2012 R2.  It is working for users.  However, not all of the connections show up under "Monitoring".  I can connect to a server on the internal network (we don't have VPN etc. so there's no other "normal" way for me to get in unless I use the gateway), I look at the Monitoring view, and I don't see the very connection I'm using.

Are there situations that cause the gateway not to show connections under Monitoring?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm looking in RD Gateway Manager, not in Server Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection, after which you can see the connections under the collections

When you are in Remote desktop server> sessions, you need to "create session collections" from tasks. Once you complete the set up, in the new collections, you will find the connections

-pasha

Comment: could you clarify this?  including explaining how some connections show up but others don't?

Comment: When you are in Remote desktop server> sessions, you need to "create session collections" from tasks.
Once you complete the set up, in the new collections, you will find the connections.

Comment: There's no such setting in RD Gateway Manager.  We're talking a very simple setup, no VDI or Session Broker or anything of the sort, just basic RD Gateway functionality and management tools.

Comment: Please follow the URLs [http://screencast.com/t/CTi7cdU5xGW]

Comment: OK, you're in Server Manager, but that's for a more complicated deployment.  As I said, this is basic RD Gateway stuff.  Server Manager doesn't like this configuration - it insists on a session broker, etc.  So I don't have the option you're giving.  I'm looking in basic, old school RD Gateway Manager, not Server Manager.

Comment: you shall get the gateway manager only when u install the RD service. and its diffrent in 2012 onwards. secondly you can use task manager to find the conenctions

Comment: I have the RD Gateway Manager.  I have it on the gateway server and on a management station through RSAT.  Task Manager doesn't show gateway connections.  You don't need the RD service to get RD gateway, they are different services.

Comment: I got your query, and i have tracked the issue is with set up.
FOLLOW THE url [LINK](http://www.lemonbits.com/2014/06/20/installing-standalone-remote-desktop-gateway-on-the-windows-server-2012-r2-without-complete-remote-desktop-services-infrastructure/) FOR ASSSITANCE.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer.  The link shows nothing we haven't done.  The gateway works.  It just doesn't show sessions in monitoring reliably.

Comment: it was same for me when i wanted t check connections to RDP, but as i understand this works when you are creating a session over your RDweb and accessing the application.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an external FQDN of the remote desktop server that was in use before we implemented gateway.

As it was getting connected without the need of the gateway, user sessions were not showing under the gateway monitoring.

Once I started using internal name along with rd gateway settings, connections started to show up under monitoring.